# Laravel return two models together?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, orm, axios

i have a view which displays some places and i'm fetching this data from my API, the model places have many to many relationship with categories. Is there any way i can fetch both model data from the controller?

Like i have this function to fetch all the places, how can i fetch their categories together?

```
 public function get_places()
    {
        return  Places::all();
        
    }
```

I know by finding the place with it's id i can do something like $place->categories, but this is not what i'm looking for since i want to fetch and display all of them together in a Vue Component. I'm looking more something like `Places::all()->with(Categories::class)`
Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok using `Places::with('categories')->get();` solved my problem and was exactly what i was looking and thinking of.